# office 365 email status delivered, but recipient not receive or quarantine

Tags: microsoft-office-365

our company recently migrate out gmail to o365, it running fine for one month, after that,a lot of recipient are complaining not receive any email from our company, we have checked admin console, and the status shown the message deliver status as "delivered".
recipient not found in junk/quarantine console.  any possible to trace? we have submitted question to consultant and escalated to Microsoft, also not able to answer.

Comment: If Office 365 shows the emails as being delivered then they were delivered. The problem is on the recipient side. You can run a message trace to confirm that and look at the details of the message trace.

Comment: problem is 90% recipient facing same problem. our console status shown delivered. but recipient no receive email. some show not even have log

Comment: Why don't you start by running a message trace for some of the emails, like I suggested.

Comment: U mean start trace from sender or recipient? Sender got. But all recipient not really able to provide

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/message-not-delivered-but-message-trace/355f541e-c217-4feb-ab50-a76fcf89830f.    Similar like this